# PHP rounding, round/ceil/floor??

Tags: php

Say I have the two following numbers:

```
$a = 77.5;
$b = 74.5;
```

How would I get the following:

```
$a = 80;
$b = 70;
```

I have looked at round, ceil and floor but I can't figure out how to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP supports negative precision for its [`round`](http://php.net/round) function:

```
$a = round($a, -1);
```

it's pretty much the same as writing:

```
$a = round($a/10)*10;
```

Comment: 53 seconds, damn! Didn't mean to poach your answer, Flight Of The Conchords got in me way.

Comment: steve, hooray for flight of the conchords \o/

Comment: Grrrr...it was Business Time... :)

Answer (score 2):

You've got to move your decimals over some, then `ceil`-ify.

```
ceil($a/10)*10
```